# Function dosent work with form element. I need also reset button, but it works only with <form> element

Tags: javascript, function

In my program I have 3 functions:

1. Amounts must be added together and their total must be shown in.
2. Second calculates the VAT.
3. The third one resets everything.

So the question is: the reset button works only with `<form>` element.
But with `<form>` element I have a bug with reprodusing VAT resultat. It apears on 1 second, and disapears. I think it have something with reset finction. Please help me to understand. If I change  on , then  VAT button works, but reset button - no!

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  </HEAD>
    <BODY> 
    <h2>Onderdeel 1</h2>   
    <h2>The Sum Program</h2>   
    <hr/>
     <form id="myForm">
      <button type="button" onclick="check_field('myInput');"value = ''>Enter</button>
      <input id="myInput">
      <p>Uw totaal:</p>
      <input type="number" id="output">
      <button type="button" onclick="check_field('myInput');"value = ''>Enter</button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button onclick="getBTW()">get BTW</button>
      </br>
      <p>Prijs zonder BTW <input id="prijsZonderBTW"> </p>
      <p> Btw <input id="btw"> </p>
      <button onclick="myReset()">reset</button>
    </form>
    <script>
       var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
       var output = document.getElementById("output");
       var total = 0;
     function check_field(id) {
            var field = document.getElementById(id);
            if (isNaN(field.value)) {
                alert('not a number');
            } else {
              return myFunction();
            }
        }
     function myFunction() {
        total += +input.value;
        output.value = total;
        input.value = "";
      }
      function myReset() {
       document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
      }
      function getBTW() {
        var prijs = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
        var prijsZonderBTW = (prijs/121)*100;
        var btw = prijs - prijsZonderBTW;
        document.getElementById("prijsZonderBTW").value = prijsZonderBTW.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("btw").value = btw.toFixed(2);
     }
        </script>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a fair amount of tweaks here. the main ones are:
1) use input type="button" instead of button. only 1 button per form and it submits the form so thats what was happening
2) swapped user input to type="number" so that validating it wasnt necessary
3) got rid of global variables, moved them into the function scope that needed them
4) in getBTW use the output.value instead of myInput which gets cleared every time the + button is clicked

Hopefully these tweaks make sense and set you on the right track for where you are headed

```js
function myFunction() {
  const input = document.getElementById("myInput"),
    output = document.getElementById("output");
  let total = +output.value || 0;
  total += +input.value;
  output.value = total;
  input.value = "";
}
function getBTW() {
  var prijs = +document.getElementById("output").value;
  var prijsZonderBTW = (prijs/121)*100;
  var btw = prijs - prijsZonderBTW;
  document.getElementById("prijsZonderBTW").value = prijsZonderBTW.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("btw").value = btw.toFixed(2);
}
function myReset() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

```html
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  </HEAD>
    <BODY> 
    <h2>Onderdeel 1</h2>   
    <h2>The Sum Program</h2>   
    <hr/>
     <form id="myForm">
      <label>User Entry</label>
      <input type="number" id="myInput">
      <input type="button" value="+" onclick="myFunction()">
      <br>
      <label>Uw totaal:</label>
      <input type="number" id="output" disabled>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="button" onclick="getBTW()" value="get BTW">
      </br>
      <p>Prijs zonder BTW <input type="text" id="prijsZonderBTW" disabled> </p>
      <p> Btw <input type="text" id="btw" disabled> </p>
      <input type="button" onclick="myReset()" value="reset">
    </form>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```